# cross-browser server side web app logging library

Tags: debugging, logging, firefox-addon, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

To send debug messages from our web application to the browser, we have Firebug+[FirePHP](http://firephp.org/) for Firefox, as well as [Chrome Logger](http://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger/) for Chrome/Chromium. [FirePHP for Chrome](https://github.com/andrewn/firephp-chrome) does not work with the latest Chromium/Chrome versions and does not seem to get developed anymore.

Unfortunately, both tools are incompatible because they use a different format and thus require different server-side libraries.

Is there a way to make them compatible, or an alternative that works across browsers?

Comment: +1 because this annoys me too. As a developer we need tools like this to be cross-browser. Apparently there's [a version of FirePHP for Chrome](https://github.com/andrewn/firephp-chrome). I haven't tested it, but it sounds like a good start. But I'd rather see Chrome Logger ported to other browsers, as it supports multiple languages on the server side.

Comment: "FirePHP for Chrome" is not compatible with current chromium versions :/

Comment: hmm, a pity. as I said, I didn't try it out; I just googled and spotted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Webug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webug/cjbeipenlpoeifpkjhgakejmikdhlhcj) for Chrome implements the FirePHP protocol, so FirePHP can be used cross-browser now.